# What are the texts associated with the six Vedangas?

Tags: vedanga

The six Vedangas are Siksha, Chhanda, Vyakarana, Nirukta, Jyotisha and Kalpa. It seems the texts associated with them are not of the same name for example, Asthadhayi and Mahabhasya are associated with the Vyakarana.

Is there any mention (in scriptures or works of saints) about texts associated with the six Vedangas?

Comment: Some of them are mentioned [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27950/2770)

Comment: See this website: http://vedicheritage.gov.in/vedangas/