# Which is the first text to mention 6 Darshanas?

Tags: shad-darshana

While talking about Vedanga, we know that six Vedangas are [mentioned](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27948/277) in Mundaka Upanishad, Nirukta and [in](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27949/277) Puranas. Likewise I want to know which is the text that mentions or introduces six Darshanas, also known as Shad Darshanas (षड्दर्शनानि). Is the term **Shada Darshana** mentioned in Puranas or in any other text?

Answer (score 5):

> - Is the term Shada Darshana mentioned in Puranas or in any other text?

I have found the term mentioned in the KulArnava Tantram twice.

> **Shada-darsana** mahAkupe patitAh pashavah priye|
>  ParamArtham na jAnanti pashupAshaniyantritAh ||
>
> The Pashus are fallen into a giant well of the form of the six
>   philosophies (Shadadarshana mahAkupa). Bounded by the PAshas, these
>   persons do not know about the supreme truth (ParamArtha).
>
> **1.87**

> **Shada-darshanAni** mehAngAni padau kukshih karau shirah |
>  Teshu bhedantu
>   yah kurjAnmAngam chedayettu sah ||
>
> The six philosophies are my six limbs viz:- two legs, two hands, the
>   torso and the head. Discriminating between them is equivalent to
>   cutting my limbs (Angachedana).
>
> **2.85**

The names of some of these philosophies (like VedAnta, MimAngsa etc) are found separately in the PurAna Devi BhAgavatam but probably the term Shad Darshana is not mentioned.

Comment: Very nice find Sir

Comment: Thank you @Viraj sir :)